# What are the contents of unused memory in unions?

Tags: c++, unions, stack-memory

Suppose I have a union:

```
union foo {
    char a;
    int i;
}
```

on a platform where `sizeof foo.i` > `sizeof foo.a`.

If I assign to `foo.a`, what happens to the rest of the memory which was previously part of `foo.i`?

Comment: Does it matter?  If you are trying to cast two different types using a union note that that is undefined in C++.

Comment: Nothing happens to it. Accessing it is simply undefined. In practice, it probably contains the same value that it originally had, but that is not guaranteed. What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @cody - it's not safe to say that **nothing** happens to it.  It may be overwritten or not; that's up to the compiler.  All that is safe to say is that reading through any other member is now undefined behaviour.

Comment: It is UB because the standard has nothing to say about it, but why would the compiler treat writing to `int i` in a union differently than it would treat writing to `int i` as a local variable or as a class member (`p->i`)? This absolutely seems like something the standard *ought* to cover.

Comment: @toby By that I meant that the standard does not specify that anything in particular happens to it. I thought that was made clear by the remainder of my comment. Guess not.

Comment: @kfsone - the compiler is more likely to treat writes to `char a` in a union differently to `char a` elsewhere - for instance, in architectures where byte addressing involves a read-modify-write cycle, this can be avoided if it's known that writing a full machine word is safe.

Comment: hello,I am a beginner to c++ programming.I am inquisitive about whether i any way can i access the rest of the memory which was part of foo.i?

Answer (score 2):

It is undefined what happens to the memory you have not written to.  The compiler may choose to leave its contents untouched.  It may (e.g. for performance reasons) overwrite the previous contents with arbitrary values.

It is Unspecified Behaviour to read from `foo.i` after writing `foo.a` for exactly this reason.

Comment: Are you sure this is *undefined behavior* and not *unspecified or implementation-defined behavior*?

Comment: I meant to write *Unspecified* - thanks for the correction, @zulan.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, the C11 standard is very clear about this in 6.2.6.1.7:

> When a value is stored in a member of an object of union type, the bytes of the object representation that do not correspond to that member but do correspond to other members take **unspecified values**.

Unfortunately, I have not found anything as clear in the C++14 standard. Section 9.5.:

> In a union, at most one of the non-static data members can be active at any time, that is, the value of at
>   most one of the non-static data members can be stored in a union at any time. [ Note: One special guarantee
>   is made in order to simplify the use of unions: If a standard-layout union contains several standard-layout
>   structs that share a common initial sequence (9.2), and if an object of this standard-layout union type
>   contains one of the standard-layout structs, it is **permitted to inspect the common initial sequence** of any of
>   standard-layout struct members; see 9.2. — end note ]

This guarantee is oddly specific, I cannot find any guarantee regarding *layout-compatible members*. Nevertheless, two types of different size are not *layout-compatible*, could not be part of a *common initial sequences*. So I guess the standard would **not permit to inspect the inactive members**.

That would be a case towards **undefined behavior** when accessing the values, although I would believe that **unspecified values** make more sense.